# How to backup single post in wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts, single, backup

Please Advice me. I wanted to backup single post with data and media file. 
But not link with original post.

Comment: Your browser has that feature: Just hit `Ctrl` + `s`, and save as complete page.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the backup of your post or pages by using the        `tools => export`  option present in wordpress. On the export page you can see multiple filters like date, users and status through which you can take the backup of your posts or pages.

Comment: Thanks. But, it is in xml file. I just want full data for single post. Using 'updraftplus' plugin, we can download whole site. Like this I need for single post related files

Comment: Yes it will be in xml form. But when you import it (xml file ) then it will again in the same look as you had in wordpress dashboard with all the content like media.

Comment: Yes, You are right. But,  If the customer lost original post, How xml link refer the original post?.  Using updraftplus plugin we can backup whole sites. Just I need the same as like backup for specific post.

Comment: If a customer lost the original post then you have to follow the two steps completely remove the original post and then import the xml file. Customer can see the same post with the same id and same content. You can save the post in xml file by using the post id in the name of the xml file for your easiness. In this way you can easily upload the backup of the post. Shortly by the post id you can link the original and backup of the post.

Comment: Ok. I will do the same way. Thanks. But there are no plugin for the individual post backup right?

Comment: Welcome. Actually when a functionality exist by default in the wordpress then there are rare chances of such plugins that have the same functionality. I have seen many plugins for backup but till now I am not able to see any plugin that take the backup of only single post individually.
However, you can create a plugin yourself for this purpose.